# How to fill in proxy information in cntlm config file?

Tags: proxy

> [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) is an NTLM / NTLM Session Response / NTLMv2 authenticating HTTP proxy intended to help you break free from the chains of Microsoft proprietary world.

I have my proxy URL in the following format:

```
http://user:passwords@my_proxy_server.com:80
```

And I have to provide this information to `cntlm`. Its config file `cntlm.ini` has following structure and parameters:

```
Username 
Domain
Password    
Proxy
```

I am not sure, how to break up my original proxy property to fill these four options?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Update your user, domain, and proxy information in `cntlm.ini`, then test your proxy with this command (run in your Cntlm installation folder):

```
cntlm -c cntlm.ini -I -M http://google.ro
```

It will ask for your password, and hopefully print your required authentication information, which must be saved in your `cntlm.ini`

Sample `cntlm.ini`:

```
Username            user
Domain              domain

# provide actual value if autodetection fails
# Workstation         pc-name

Proxy               my_proxy_server.com:80
NoProxy             127.0.0.*, 192.168.*

Listen              127.0.0.1:54321
Listen              192.168.1.42:8080
Gateway             no

SOCKS5Proxy         5000
# provide socks auth info if you want it
# SOCKS5User          socks-user:socks-password

# printed authentication info from the previous step
Auth            NTLMv2
PassNTLMv2      98D6986BCFA9886E41698C1686B58A09
```

**Note:** on linux the config file is `cntlm.conf`

Comment: Can I figure out domain from `http://user:passwords@my_proxy_server.com:80` or should I ask system-admin ?

Comment: Try commenting the `Domain domain` line and run the test, it might work.

Comment: Also you can try to add a `Password my-password` line. Sadly, I can't replicate your setup here.

Comment: You can provide the name of your PC as the value for domain, but it would be nice to post the full error messages.

Comment: Thanks I'd never have figured this out on my own. The manual didn't help.

Comment: Note on linux (Mint) the config file is cntlm.conf and this command works (without the .exe part)

Comment: @CarlPritchett thank you, I never used it under linux

Comment: What's the path for this file?

Comment: @weberc2 in practice I have always specified the full path to the config file using the `-c` option

Comment: Interesting. For posterity, I just found it at `/etc/cntlm.conf` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: In my case(on windows), I need to restart cntlm service to make it works.
Services->stop "Cntlm Authentication Proxy" -> start "Cntlm Authentication Proxy"

Comment: See [How do I know what proxy server I'm using?](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using)

Answer (score 55):

The solution takes two steps!

First, complete the user, domain, and proxy fields in `cntlm.ini`. The username and domain should probably be whatever you use to log in to Windows at your office,  eg.

```
Username            employee1730
Domain              corporate
Proxy               proxy.infosys.corp:8080
```

Then test cntlm with a command such as

```
cntlm.exe -c cntlm.ini -I -M http://www.bbc.co.uk
```

It will ask for your password (again whatever you use to log in to Windows_). Hopefully it will print 'http 200 ok' somewhere, and print your some cryptic tokens authentication information. Now add *these* to `cntlm.ini`, eg:

```
Auth            NTLM
PassNT          A2A7104B1CE00000000000000007E1E1
PassLM          C66000000000000000000000008060C8
```

Finally, set the `http_proxy` environment variable in Windows (assuming you didn't change with the `Listen` field which by default is set to `3128`) to the following

```
http://localhost:3128
```

Answer (score 20):

Without any configuration, you can simply issue the following command (modifying `myusername` and `mydomain` with your own information):

```
cntlm -u myusername -d mydomain -H
```

or

```
cntlm -u myusername@mydomain -H
```

It will ask you the password of `myusername` and will give you the following output:

```
PassLM          1AD35398BE6565DDB5C4EF70C0593492
PassNT          77B9081511704EE852F94227CF48A793
PassNTLMv2      A8FC9092D566461E6BEA971931EF1AEC    # Only for user 'myusername', domain 'mydomain'
```

Then create the file `cntlm.ini` (or `cntlm.conf` on Linux using default path) with the following content (replacing your `myusername`, `mydomain` and `A8FC9092D566461E6BEA971931EF1AEC` with your information and the result of the previous command):

```
Username    myusername
Domain      mydomain

Proxy       my_proxy_server.com:80
NoProxy     127.0.0.*, 192.168.*

Listen      127.0.0.1:5865
Gateway     yes

SOCKS5Proxy 5866

Auth        NTLMv2
PassNTLMv2  A8FC9092D566461E6BEA971931EF1AEC
```

Then you will have a local open proxy on local port `5865` and another one understanding SOCKS5 protocol at local port `5866`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a guide on how to use cntlm

### What is cntlm?

cntlm is an NTLM/NTLMv2 authenticating HTTP proxy

It takes the address of your proxy and opens a listening socket, forwarding each request to the parent proxy

### Why cntlm?

Using cntlm we make it possible to run tools like `choro, pip3, apt-get` from a command line

```
pip3 install requests
choco install git
```

The main advantage of cntlm is password protection.

With cntlm you can use password hashes.

So **NO PLAINTEXT PASSWORD** in `%HTTP_PROXY%` and `%HTTPS_PROXY%` environment variables

### Install cntlm

You can get the latest cntlm release from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/latest/download)

#### Note! Username and domain

My username is `zezulinsky`

My domain is `local`

When I run commands I use `zezulinsky@local`

Place your username when you run commands

#### Generate password hash

Run a command

```
cntlm -u zezulinsky@local -H
```

Enter your password:

```
Password:
```

As a result you are getting hashed password:

```
PassLM          AB7D42F42QQQQ407552C4BCA4AEBFB11
PassNT          PE78D847E35FA7FA59710D1231AAAF99
PassNTLMv2      46738B2E607F9093296AA4C319C3A259
```

### Verify your generated hash is valid

Run a command

```
cntlm -u zezulinsky@local -M http://google.com
```

Enter your password

```
Password:
```

The result output

```
Config profile  1/4... OK (HTTP code: 301)
----------------------------[ Profile  0 ]------
Auth            NTLMv2
PassNTLMv2      46738B2E607F9093296AA4C319C3A259
------------------------------------------------
```

Note! check that PassNTLMv2 hash is the same
The resulting hash is the same for both commands

```
PassNTLMv2      46738B2E607F9093296AA4C319C3A259
```

### Change configuration file

Place generated hashes into the `cntlm.ini` configuration file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini
```

Here is how your `cntlm.ini` should look like

```
Username    zezulinsky
Domain      local
PassLM      AB7D42F42QQQQ407552C4BCA4AEBFB11
PassNT      PE78D847E35FA7FA59710D1231AAAF99
PassNTLMv2  46738B2E607F9093296AA4C319C3A259

Proxy       PROXYSERVER:8080
NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*
Listen      3128
```

### Note! newline at the end of cntlm.ini

It is important to add a newline at the end of the `cntlm.ini` configuration file

### Set your environment variables

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
```

### Check that your cntlm works

Stop all the processes named `cntlm.exe` with process explorer

Run the command

```
cntlm -u zezulinsky@local -H
```

The output looks like

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /Cntlm/cntlm.ini
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
section: local, Username = 'zezulinsky'
section: local, Domain = 'local'
section: local, PassLM = 'AB7D42F42QQQQ407552C4BCA4AEBFB11'
section: local, PassNT = 'PE78D847E35FA7FA59710D1231AAAF99'
section: local, PassNTLMv2 = '46738B2E607F9093296AA4C319C3A259'
section: local, Proxy = 'PROXYSERVER:8080'
section: local, NoProxy = 'localhost, 10.*, 127.0.0.*
section: local, Listen = '3128'
Default config file opened successfully
cntlm: Proxy listening on 127.0.0.1:3128
Adding no-proxy for: 'localhost'
Adding no-proxy for: '10.*'
Adding no-proxy for: '127.0.0.*'
cntlm: Workstation name used: MYWORKSTATION
cntlm: Using following NTLM hashes: NTLMv2(1) NT(0) LM(0)
cntlm: PID 1234: Cntlm ready, staying in the foreground
```

Open a new cmd and run a command:

```
pip3 install requests
```

You should have requests python package installed

### Restart your machine

Congrats, now you have cntlm installed and configured

Answer (score 1):

Just to add , if you are performing a "pip" operation , you might need to add and additional "--proxy=localhost:port_number"

e.g `pip install --proxy=localhost:3128 matplotlib`

Visit this [link](http://thebongtraveller.blogspot.in/2016/11/cntlm-in-office.html) to see full details.

Answer (score 0):

Once you generated the file, and changed your password, you can run as below,

```
cntlm -H
```

Username will be the same. it will ask for password, give it, then copy the PassNTLMv2, edit the cntlm.ini, then just run the following

```
cntlm -v
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Sasha Zezulinsky.

In windows:
I used
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128

When it was set to
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128, it never worked.

Below posts are also very helpful.
[How to use pip on windows behind an authenticating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698557/how-to-use-pip-on-windows-behind-an-authenticating-proxy#)

Answer (score -3):

For me just using `cntlm -H` wasn't generating the right hash, but it does with the command below providing the user name.

If you need to generate a new password hash for cntlm, because you have change it or you've been forced to update it, you can just type the below command and update your cntlm.conf configuration file with the output:

```
$ cntlm -u test -H
Password: 
PassLM          D2AABAF8828482D5552C4BCA4AEBFB11
PassNT          83AC305A1582F064C469755F04AE5C0A
PassNTLMv2      4B80D9370D353EE006D714E39715A5CB    # Only for user 'test', domain ''
```

Comment: This post is completely missing the information, that domain and username must be set for the NTLMv2 hash to work correctly, and also how and where to store this info.