# NPM behind NTLM proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, ntlm, http-proxy

Is it possible to run [`npm install`](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) behind an HTTP proxy, which uses [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) authentication? If yes, how can I set the server's address and port, the username, and the password?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I solved it this way (OS: Windows XP SP3):

**1.** Download [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) installer and run it.

**2.** Find and fill in these fields in cntlm.ini. *Do not fill in the `Password` field, it's never a good idea to store unencrypted passwords in text files.*

```
Username    YOUR_USERNAME
Domain      YOUR_DOMAIN
Proxy       YOUR_PROXY_IP:PORT
Listen      53128
```

**3.** Open console, and type these commands to generate password hashes.

```
> cd c:\the_install_directory_of_cntlm
> cntlm -H
Password: ...type proxy password here...
PassLM          D6888AC8AE0EEE294D954420463215AE
PassNT          0E1FAED265D32EBBFB15F410D27994B2
PassNTLMv2      91E810C86B3FD1BD14342F945ED42CD6
```

**4.** Copy the above three lines into cntlm.ini, under the `Domain` field's line. *Once more, do not fill in the `Password` field.* Save cntlm.ini.

**5.** Open the Service Manager (from command line: services.msc), and start the service called "CNTLM Authentication Proxy".

**6.** In the console, type these lines:

```
> npm config set proxy http://localhost:53128
> npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:53128
> npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

**7.** Now `npm view`, `npm install` etc. should work. Example:

```
> npm view qunit
...nice answer, no errors :)
```

Comment: You can start cntlm directly from the command line with `net start cntlm`

Comment: For using NTLM authorization with CNTLM, follow below instructions:
1. After step-2, run this commandline command 
      cntlm -I -M http://www.google.co.in
2. Prompts for domain password - copy it into cntlm.ini and restart service
3. Generates following password hash
Auth            NTLM
PassNT          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PassLM          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: found link where it explained in detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/15437508/224700

Comment: great solution thanks, one note - on point 6 above the address url should be prefixed with http rather than https

Comment: For anyone who does not like to use windows service or have information in INI file, here is another way: download a portalbe version; remove domain/username/password completely from INI file; start the tool from command line by using `cntlm -c cntlm.ini -v -a ntlm -I` (sure you can create a bat file to wrap it); enter your password every time you start the tool.

Comment: To fix connection errors on some NTLM proxies, configure this header in Cntml : "Header  Connection: close"

Comment: if you need to debug connections or check if your config is correct, start it with `cntlm -c cntlm.ini -v`  it will stay in the foreground (cmd line) and will give lot's of useful information.

Comment: why changing the registry? what is the problem with default one(s) ?

Comment: @MichalBernhard Not sure if this is the correct answer, but I noticed when the registry was set to default (`https://registry.npmjs.org`) `npm install <pkg>@<version>` would "get stuck" on an operation like: `fetchMetadata: http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isurl 280ms (from cache)` or `fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule uuid@2.0.3 checking installable status`. Once I changed the registry as suggested in the answer, everything worked fine.

Comment: Not working in Windows 10. Getting this error: 
`npm ERR! code E418
npm ERR! 418 I'm a teapot - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app - got unknown host (registry.npmjs.org:80)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\faizanmubasher\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-22T07_22_44_767Z-debug.log
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 1`

Comment: I got the same issue as Faizan Mubasher directly above - solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524828#51526023). @kol - Would suggest updating the post to set the registry to http**s**://registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: @SteveChambers Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is to use [Px for Windows](https://github.com/genotrance/px) which talks NTLM on your behalf like Cntlm and NTLMAps without having to provide your credentials. It uses the logged in user's credentials via SSPI.

Comment: Gave this a go and it worked well- as good as CNTLM. No more hashed password management! I like it.

Comment: Thx for your work on this tool! This should definitely be the answer to this thread!
I was unable to make cntlm worked, my credentials were always rejected by the proxy (407). Px works like a charm!

Comment: Hell yeah! This great tool! And npm work great with px, when cntlm hangs.

Comment: PX worked for me, while CNTLM didn't. PX also worked smoothly with maven, IntelliJ and JVM's in general.

Answer (score 11):

CNTLM answer was working for me, but with connection errors make npm unusable. I've fixed them by adding this header in CNTML.

```
Header      Connection: close
```

Comment: Hi Toilal, is that header needed when you do many requests via npm install because then 20 times npm stops due to network problems... will that fix the problem when you do an initial npm install after check out a repo?

Comment: @HelloWorld seems so. (old answer, I don't have to use CNTML anymore)

Comment: I use the python proxy px now, works much better/more stable!

Answer (score 9):

Rather than running CNTLM, you could instead try running [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) when you need to use npm. I've found this works in fairly locked down environments (e.g. investment banks). It's also a tool that is fairly easy to make a business case for (if you need to) since it's invaluable for checking/creating/altering HTTP traffic.

I've had to go this route before due to usage of smartpass authentication - i.e. we didn't actually have passwords. At those locations setting up CNTLM would have been impossible.

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work until I enabled the rule 
`Automatically Authenticate`

Comment: You saved me! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the settings as parameters:

```
npm --proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:port --proxy-https=http://username:password@proxyserver:port --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/ install whateveryouwanttoinstall
```

Comment: This is Basic Authentication, not NTLM.

Comment: @kol, that's true, but the proxies that use NTLM auth, frequently, allow basic auth too. In my opinion, the issue with this method is the storage of its personal password in the NPM configuration.

Comment: is it not https-proxy instead of proxy-https?

Comment: I downvoted because this is basic auth, and it is NOT TRUE that most ntlm proxies also allow basic auth. This is completely up to the sysadmins to decide and not some default that is usually "true".

Answer (score 5):

CNTLM didn't work for me. I tried all possible combinations. NPM was giving Authentication error. Fiddler came for rescue and saved my time. It is easy to install and configure. Set Fiddler Rule to Automatically Authenticated.In .npmrc set these

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
strict-ssl=false
```

It worked for me :)

**Another Fiddler Option:**

A second way to make Fiddler act as an HTTP proxy for NTLM and other protocols is to leave the auto authenticate options/rules defaults in place and go to this setting from the menu bar:

Tools > Telerik Fiddler Options > Connections tab

Click on the *Allow remote computers to connect* checkbox. You will see a dialog explaining the consequences of enabling this option. Restart Fiddler and update the *.npmrc* file as shown above. Whenever you need npm to access the registry site just run Fiddler. This setting won't affect the way Fiddler runs for other captures.

Comment: You could still use cntlm, you just need to set those proxy lines as whatever the listen port is in your cntlm.ini file. CNTLM would be necessary if you were authenticating to the proxy with credentials

Answer (score 5):

1. Open your `.npmrc` file in C:\users\username\ folder using notepad
2. Add the below lines..
3. Replace domain, username, pwd, servername with your correct values
4. Try to install or get packages now
5. If trying from Vs2017, close and reopen VS IDE, then only it works

   ```
   proxy=http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PWD@proxy.servername.com:6050   
   https-proxy=http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PWD@proxy.servername.com:6050  
   http-proxy=http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PWD@proxy.servername.com:6050   
   strict-ssl=false
   ```

Comment: This worked for me. All I have to do is urlencode the values. My password had some special characters.

Answer (score 0):

CNTLM worked for me as suggested by KOL. Thanks KOL for that. Just wanted to add that there are some oddities in individual proxies because of which the password may not be acceptable when using simple `cntlm -H`.

Use `cntlm -I -M http://test.com` and copy the below config after erasing older configs and you should be through.

The output is like

```
---------------------------------------------------
Auth            NTLM
PassNT          8EE9B595A89F7D8774C2146FB302CBCF
PassLM          78901DA9889727EDE28EF9F2769485B9
----------------------------------------------------
```