# How can I tell if cntlm is running?

Tags: proxy

related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569054/npm-behind-ntlm-proxy/18570201#18570201)

How can I tell if cntlm is running? I have tried task manager and do not see it running even after pressing this `Start Cntlm Authentication Proxy`

**background**: 
trying to do an npm install and getting `npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

pretty sure I have cntlm set up correctly as had it working before

Comment: Did you look on the Services tab? (Or look in Process Explorer, which shows services)

Comment: tks see it in Services tab and its running. so its not that issue then. tks

Comment: @EricLaw, Although, sometimes I am pretty sure I have seen it in the process list, what is the difference between service and process exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check from a command line try this:

```
sc query cntlm
```

This command should return something like this, if CNTLM is running:

```
SERVICE_NAME: cntlm
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

If stopped the result looks like this:

```
SERVICE_NAME: cntlm
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 1  STOPPED
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Answer (score 3):

CNTLM is a service! so you have to open services.msc(for windows) and check if service is running or not! Always use this way to start server instead of starting from start menu.

TIP: if you try to start from your windows start menu you, that command window would disappear immediately so you can not see what error is there.Just go to that folder and open command prompt(keep pressing shift key and then right click gives you option to open command prompt at that folder.) and execute that exe(the one you see at start menu start cntlm server). Now you will see if service started successfully or not!

If you want to check it is working or not,You can check simply with the help of firefox!

1. GO to Preferences >> Advanced >> Network >> Connection >> settings >> select Manual proxy settings
2. put host as localhost and port as 3128 . (the one which you set inside cntlm config file as listening port)
3. Check if you want browse internet inside firefox or not! if it says proxy server unreachable or refusing connections, you got problem and if you can browse internet then your cntlm is working ok.