# npm install <package> + using cntlm + unable to install packages

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569054/npm-behind-ntlm-proxy/18570201#18570201) which i have set up correctly as the `npm install <package>` was working before

but now I am getting this, but i am not sure what has changed. Does anyone have any advice?

```
UserName@WIECL0276 ~$ npm config list
; cli configs
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
user-agent = "npm/1.4.14 node/v0.10.29 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\UserName\.npmrc
https-proxy = "https://localhost:53128/"
proxy = "http://localhost:53128/"

; globalconfig C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
proxy = "http://localhost:53128/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\cygwin64\home\UserName
; HOME = C:\Users\UserName
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.


UserName@WIECL0276 ~
$ npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

UserName@WIECL0276 ~
$ npm install csv
    npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

.
.
.

```
    npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
    npm
```

Comment: came in to work to day, turned pc on and it seems to work. no idea, see answer below

Answer (score 0):

came in to work to day, turned pc on and it seems to work. no idea

```
UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ ls
npm-debug.log  package.json  server.js

UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ npm install packages
packages@0.0.5 node_modules\packages
├── toarray@0.0.1
├── type-component@0.0.1
├── factories@0.0.7 (protoclass@0.0.2)
├── resolver@0.1.12 (mime@1.2.11, fetch@0.3.6)
└── express@3.4.8 (methods@0.1.0, fresh@0.2.0, merge-descriptors@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.1, range-parser@0.0.4, debug@0.8.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.1.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, send@0.1.4, commander@1.3.2, connect@2.12.0)

UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ ls
node_modules  package.json  server.js

UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ ls node_modules/
packages

UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ npm install
express@3.12.1 node_modules\express
├── parseurl@1.0.1
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.4
├── vary@0.1.0
├── media-typer@0.2.0
├── fresh@0.2.2
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── methods@1.0.1
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.3
├── depd@0.3.0
├── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.1 (ipaddr.js@0.1.2)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── debug@1.0.2 (ms@0.6.2)
├── send@0.4.3 (mime@1.2.11, finished@1.2.2)
└── connect@2.21.1 (pause@0.0.1, connect-timeout@1.1.1, qs@0.6.6, finalhandler@0.0.2, response-time@2.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, on-headers@0.0.0, morgan@1.1.1, serve-static@1.2.3, serve-favicon@2.0.1, method-override@2.0.2, vhost@2.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, cookie-parser@1.3.2, type-is@1.3.2, serve-index@1.1.4, errorhandler@1.1.1, express-session@1.5.2, compression@1.0.8, csurf@1.2.2, body-parser@1.4.3, multiparty@3.2.9)

UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ ls
node_modules  package.json  server.js

UserName@WIECL0276 ~/nodeMongoDB_REST/nodecellar
$ ls node_modules/
express  packages
```