# nodejs npm package install failed

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am new to nodejs, and I have just installed it in my Windows 7 PC. The next thing I try to do is to install express.js package via npm `npm install express --save`, and I got following error messages

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-0.1.6.tgz
npm ERR! Error: 403 Forbidden
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\fetch.js:58:12)
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1610:14
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:102:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd C:\temp\NodeJS_POC
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Are you by chance behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, behind NTLM proxy, but I have installed CNTLM tool (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569054/npm-behind-ntlm-proxy) to enable regular proxy for npm. I ran `npm view qunit` command and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, just got back from this morning. Glad to see you found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns to be our proxy server actually blocks http://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-0.1.6.tgz