# Set Proxy in Mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

```
defmodule Elixirrest.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :elixirrest,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:maru, "~> 0.13"}
    ]
  end
end
```

When I run

```
mix do deps.get, compile
```

I receive:

> Could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency `:maru`
>   Shall I install Hex? (if running non-interactively, use `"mix local.hex --force"`) [Yn] y
>
> ** (Mix) httpc request failed with: {:could_no_establish_ssh_tunnel, {'HTTP/1.1', 407, 'Proxy Authorization Required'}}
>
> Could not install Hex because Mix could not download metadata at https://repo.hex.pm/installs/hex-1.x.csv.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to configure proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898007/mix-does-not-work-behind-proxy. This question has an answer already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mix does not work behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898007/mix-does-not-work-behind-proxy)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to export the proxy settings through environment variables.

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ab302d23e4b632486645cdf0fcc392e66b7abb99/lib/mix/lib/mix/utils.ex#L609-L614

```
  defp proxy_env do
    http_proxy = System.get_env("HTTP_PROXY") || System.get_env("http_proxy")
    https_proxy = System.get_env("HTTPS_PROXY") || System.get_env("https_proxy")
    no_proxy = no_proxy_env() |> no_proxy_list()

    {proxy_setup(:http, http_proxy, no_proxy), proxy_setup(:https, https_proxy, no_proxy)}
  end
```