# Running npm behind a corporate firewall: what do I need to tell the security team?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run node.js but cannot install any packages as `npm` is blocked. I have tried the solutions here: [How to fill in proxy information in cntlm config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181637/how-to-fill-proxy-information-in-cntlm-config-file/15437508#15437508), and here: [NPM behind NTLM proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569054/npm-behind-ntlm-proxy/18570201#18570201) and still received errors. I have tripled checked that I have followed the instructions and my ini has the same configuration as the instructions.

My next step is to ask the security team to allow `npm` access through the firewall, but I cannot see any documentation about this. What do I need to tell the security team?

Note: I am aware of `npm` Enterprise but I think before I get to that step I need to get established with `npm`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeah, in your simplest case all you need to do is one of these

```
npm config set proxy http://company.com:8000
```

or

```
npm config set https-proxy http://company.com:8000
```

where http://company.com:8000 is your proxy server and port

(note the - dash, **not** _ underscore)

Also can you test access to http://registry.npmjs.org the npm registry from that machine.

Additionally your package.json also contains dependencies that require the pulling of a git repository code. You may (most likely will) need to configure [git to use a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) as well.

Comment: This site is a pretty good reference http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/

Answer (score 4):

If you come here searching for an `iptables` rule:

If you want to allow only `npm` traffic for a certain user, the following might work:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner <username> -d registry.npmjs.org --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```