# Eclipse is not connecting with the Internet

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to use eclipse to run unfolding map online for mooc course I am enrolling  . But eclipse is not connecting to the internet. I set up proxy and run the browser through eclipse to check the connection but immediately the eclipse exit when the browser open the webpage. I tried on processing IDE as well but not connected with internet. the same error shown.. the error on eclipse looks the following.

```
Unfolding Map v0.9.7 (UCSD edition)
Using OpenGLMapDisplay with processing.opengl.PGraphics2D
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:989)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:986)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(PApplet.java:7267)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(PApplet.java:7235)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadBytes(PApplet.java:7462)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(PApplet.java:5879)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.getTileFromUrl(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:989)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:986)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(PApplet.java:7267)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(PApplet.java:7235)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadBytes(PApplet.java:7462)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(PApplet.java:5879)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.getTileFromUrl(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
The file "http://mt1.google.com/vt/v=w2p.116&hl=de&x=178&y=413&z=10&s=Galileo" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:989)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:986)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(PApplet.java:7267)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(PApplet.java:7235)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadBytes(PApplet.java:7462)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(PApplet.java:5879)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.getTileFromUrl(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:989)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:986)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(PApplet.java:7267)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(PApplet.java:7235)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadBytes(PApplet.java:7462)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(PApplet.java:5879)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.getTileFromUrl(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
The file "http://mt1.google.com/vt/v=w2p.116&hl=de&x=177&y=412&z=10&s=Galileo" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://mt1.google.com/vt/v=w2p.116&hl=de&x=178&y=411&z=10&s=Galileo" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://mt1.google.com/vt/v=w2p.116&hl=de&x=178&y=412&z=10&s=Galileo" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Do you connect to the internet using a proxy ?

Comment: through the network connection I choosed manual and set up HTTP. I tried too the other two option Native and direct but not connecting.

Comment: Does this mean "yes, I have to use a proxy to connect to the Internet" ?

Comment: yes I have to use to connect.

Answer (score 2):

When setting the proxy make sure to choose *Active Provider: Manual* and check again your proxy settings (HOST and Port). I had similar problem with connecting Eclipse to internet on my workstation and the problem turned out to be the *Active Provider* settings.

Comment: i checked it is right. I opened web browser of eclipse and opened google, it is open the problem is when the page open immediately the eclipse exit.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to take a different approach to tell Eclipse which proxy needs to be used:

```
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=name.of.proxy
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=name.of.proxy
```

You can put this into your eclipse.ini.

If your proxy needs you to authenticate and only supports Windows credentials it might help to introduce a intermediary proxy like CNTLM. [CNTLM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181637/how-to-fill-proxy-information-in-cntlm-config-file) then receives your credentials to authenticate with the proxy and provides a proxy to your application which does *not* need authentication. But it depends on your setup if you need this.

Comment: thank you, I tried but is not working yet. I edit the code on the question which i got it when i run the eclipse again, can you check it the code again?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348) link for detailed steps regarding how to install cntlm you need to point your system proxy settings to ctlm server localhost:3128(default port)

Answer (score 0):

Marged's answer is right, but you have to set

```
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=name.of.proxy
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=name.of.proxy
```

inside your applet run configuration WM arguments.
Run configurations > Arguments > VM arguments

Answer (score -1):

you can avoid it simply with the use of any VPN service, your IP is making too many request most probably because you have used it alot while making your project, google thought it as an system generated repeated requests.
you can avoid it for a while by using VPN. ENJOY..!!