# Filling proxy information in cntlm config file

Tags: linux, windows, proxy, cygwin, ntlm

I have followed the procedure below to fill proxy information in cntlm.ini.

It worked fine and I was able to authenticate properly.

[How to fill proxy information in cntlm config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181637/how-to-fill-proxy-information-in-cntlm-config-file/15437508#15437508)

However, Windows required a password change. After the password, I would need to change the password: eg.

```
Auth            NTLMv2
PassNTLMv2      98D6986BCFA9886E41698C1686B58A09 (New Encrypted Password).
```

By using this command below, to obtain the new encrypted password to go in the cntlm.ini file.

```
cntlm.exe -c cntlm.ini -I -M http://www.bbc.co.uk
```

But i get the exception below:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBbvw.png)

Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: It is warning not an error. It is due to `cntlm` using an old cygwin1.dll https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-find_fast_cwd-warnings

Answer (score 0):

The the old password needed to removed from the .config file so that I could get a new one.